# How to get a usable PSR-7 HTTP client from Laravel app without being restricted to a specific implementation?

Tags: php, laravel, psr-7

How to reproduce the problem on Laravel 9.52:

```php
$client = Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http::buildClient();
$response = $client->get('https://google.com');
```

You can easily check this in tinker. It happens to return an instance of `GuzzleHttp\Client` but I only care for PSR-7 compatibility, since I want to pass the client to a library that expects a PSR-7 compatible client.

But the client is actually not usable and the second line throws the exception that the array key `"laravel_data"` is not set.

It happens in line 1200 of `Illuminate/Http/Client/PendingRequest.php`:
https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/082345d76fc6a55b649572efe10b11b03e279d24/src/Illuminate/Http/Client/PendingRequest.php#L1200

My approach seems obvious and I did search a lot for alternatives, but to no avail. How do you do it?

Comment: It depends on the part of the Laravel application you want to get the client in. Controller? Service? Where do you need it?

Comment: you can use `GuzzleHttp/client`, he won't give you a hard time.

Comment: `GuzzleHttp\Client` implements `Psr\Http\Client\ClientInterface`, so it should be fine for your needs. You could just do `$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();` to get the client. The fact that Laravel's `buildClient()` method returns a broken client seems like a bug to me, and might be worth reporting.

Comment: `createClient` instead of `buildClient` but that is essentially the same as doing what @miken32 suggests and you'd also need to provide a guzzle handler stack.

Comment: @apokryfos I tried that, same problem.

Comment: @miken32 Could be a bug, if that method actually was intended to provide a client. It looks like it, but it is undocumented. So, if this method was NOT intended to be used by the developer, we don't have a bug here but a missing feature.

Comment: `createClient` should work but you need to provide the handler stack to it e.g. `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http::createClient(HandlerStack::create())` which is essentially like doing `new Client` which is ultimately the best way forward here. I don't think Laravel intended to be a PSR-7 client provider (given that Guzzle is already that and is what Laravel is using). You can always do `app()->bind(ClientInterface::class, Client::class)` (where Client is the guzzle client) if you want to just inject the PSR-7 client when you need to